# Jquery prettyphoto beforeclose

Tags: jquery

I am using the beforeClose method to call a jquery dialog confirm box. I am having problems closing the prettyphoto window.  Does anyone know how to do this from a dialog window?

Code example:

```
$(function(){
$("#dialogID").dialog({
open: function(event, ui){

        },
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        draggable: false,
        show: "drop",
        hide: "drop",
        zIndex: 10000,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Confirm': function(){
                $.prettyPhoto.doClose();
                $(this).dialog("close");

            },
            'No' : function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    });
```

Everything works fine but I am not able to call the close function. Any help would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at the documentation, the close function is just `close()`

```
$.prettyPhoto.close();
```